# No such file or directory: 'download.jpg'

Tags: python, email, directory, email-attachments, errno

I made a email sender a few months ago and now I have another project and I wanted to re-test this and for some reason it cannot find the JPG image which is basically in the same directory as the python file..

[image: Image same Directory as file]

```
#Email Module Imports
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
#Imports Time Modules
import time
#Imports Numeric Module Functions
import random

def EmailSender():
    #Email Variables
    email_user = 'email'  # Sender Email (hidden for reason)
    email_password = 'password'  # Sender Password (hidden for reason)
    email_send = 'emailsend'  # Receiver Email (hidden for reason)
    PORT_EMAIL = 'smtp.gmail.com' 
    PORT = 587  # Email Port
    subject = 'email test'

    emailtest = "Test"
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = email_user
    msg['To'] = email_send  
    msg['Subject'] = subject  

    body = emailtest
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
    filename = 'download.jpg' 
    Email_attachment = open(filename, 'rb')

    part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
    part.set_payload((Email_attachment).read()) 
    encoders.encode_base64(part)
    # adds email header with attachment
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= "+filename)

    msg.attach(part)  # attaches email
    text = msg.as_string()
    srv = smtplib.SMTP(PORT_EMAIL, PORT)
    srv.starttls()  # runs the email SMTP
    srv.login(email_user, email_password) 
    srv.quit()  # stops

EmailSender()
```

Comment: What is the ***current directory*** when your code is running?

Comment: @PM77-1 C:\Users\shock\Desktop\Visual Studio Code\Python\Testing\Email

Comment: (1) Have you actually verified it?  (2) Is it the same location where your file is?

Comment: @PM77-1 yes its in the same file,  it used to work before but now it just doesn't for some reason

Comment: What is the printout from the following rows?

import os
print(os.getcwd())
print(os.listdir())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative paths (folders) in respect to project has changed.
To be fool-proof, change path to jpg with absolute path derived from where the EmailSend.py is located

```
import os

currentDir= os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))  # gets the current pytho file, SendEmail.py and returns absolute path (parent directory)
filepath=os.path.join(currentDir,"download.jpg")
```

Answer (score 0):

As a follow-up to @jozefow's answer,

```py
import pathlib

cwd = pathlib.Path.cwd()
filepath = cwd / "download.jpeg"
```

The difference between their answer and mine is that mine does not assume that the current working directory is the same as the file directory.
Assumptions either way can be problematic.

The other key difference is mine is nominally more modern python.

Comment: Let consider following structure: "C:\Project\showPath\showPath.py", showPath.py will print Path.cwd()  and abspath(os.path.dirname(\__file\__))  

Open "cmd" in C:\Project\showPath\ and run python showPath.py -> both paths are the same,  lets go to C:\Project  and run: python showPath\showPath.py -> Path.cwd() will return C:\Project (where cmd was started) but abspath will return C:\Project\showPath.

In case of passing filepath from the same folder as showPath, using Path.cwd() will break when started *not* in C:\Project\showPath, in case of abspath() it will work regardless

Comment: @jozefow Like I mentioned in my answer (perhaps too subtly?) my approach does have the issue of breaking where cwd is not in the same directory as the  images. Perhaps I should update my answer to reflect the same?